# An extension to the StringBuilder

Tags: c#, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

This is another pretty basic class I wrote for a library as I *hate* the way the default `StringBuilder` in .NET works.

Essentially, I wanted to have the `+` operator, as well as implicit conversions to strings. (Rather than needing `.ToString()` all the time.)

It's pretty small and simple, so there may not be a lot to critique.

Also, before you say "just inherit `StringBuilder` and extend it", it's `sealed`.

```
/// <summary>
/// This wraps the .NET <code>StringBuilder</code> in a slightly more easy-to-use format.
/// </summary>
public class ExtendedStringBuilder
{
    private StringBuilder _stringBuilder;

    public string CurrentString => _stringBuilder.ToString();

    public int Length => _stringBuilder.Length;

    public ExtendedStringBuilder()
    {
        _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public ExtendedStringBuilder(int capacity)
    {
        _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity);
    }

    public ExtendedStringBuilder Append(string s)
    {
        _stringBuilder.Append(s);

        return this;
    }

    public ExtendedStringBuilder Append(char c)
    {
        _stringBuilder.Append(c);

        return this;
    }

    public ExtendedStringBuilder Append(object o)
    {
        _stringBuilder.Append(o);

        return this;
    }

    public static ExtendedStringBuilder operator +(ExtendedStringBuilder sb, string s) => sb.Append(s);

    public static ExtendedStringBuilder operator +(ExtendedStringBuilder sb, char c) => sb.Append(c);

    public static ExtendedStringBuilder operator +(ExtendedStringBuilder sb, object o) => sb.Append(o);

    public static implicit operator string(ExtendedStringBuilder sb) => sb.CurrentString;

    public override string ToString() => CurrentString;

    public string ToString(int startIndex, int length) => _stringBuilder.ToString(startIndex, length);
}
```

I didn't implement all the overloads of the `.Append` method (yet) or the `+` variants of them.

This can **literally** be used in the exact same manner as the .NET `StringBuilder`, or you can use `+=` or `+` instead of `.Append`, and you can implicitly convert it to a `string`.

Comment: What I would add is a (copy)constructor which takes a `StringBuilder` as an argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of quick comments:

You can use the [see tag's cref attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx). If you generate documentation, some tools will generate hyperlinks for you.

```
/// <summary>
/// This wraps the .NET <see cref="StringBuilder"/> in a slightly easier to use format.
/// </summary>
```

---

The length property of a `StringBuilder` is read and writable. It's also **really** useful for it to be so:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0,10))
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0},", i);
}
sb.Length--; // removes the trailing comma.
```

That's a contrived example which is trivially served with `string.Join` but setting the length can be useful!

---

The `_stringBuilder` field should be readonly.

---

I'd say `CurrentString` is superflous. Just call `_stringBuilder.ToString()`

---

I must admit, personally I think the `StringBuilder` api is really good, I've never needed an implicit conversion to a string or felt the need to `+` rather than append to them.

Comment: Except that `see` generates a link to that location, which *cannot* be followed for a link to an internal .NET library reference. (Which is why I don't use it for them.)

Comment: @EBrown - When I used to do documentation and used Sandcastle, I thought it was capable of generating MSDN links for framework classes? If you're not using Sandcastle, or I've misremembered, I'll remove that bit.